# Ansible AWX expose service by nginx ingress

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I've tried official installing guide https://asciinema.org/a/416946

and edit the instance deployment yaml as down below

but I couldn't access the awx web by virtual machine ip

OS: CentOS 7.9

awx-operater:0.16.1

```
---
apiVersion: awx.ansible.com/v1beta1
kind: AWX
metadata:
  name: awx-demo
spec:
  service_type: clusterip
  ingress_type: ingress
  hostname: my-awx.example.com
```

if I setting service_type as nodeport,

I can access awx web through minikube service url by the browser inside vm.

I just wondering how to access the awx web outside the virtual machine?

I didn't familiar with k8s or operator sdk.

Could someone give me suggestion? thx.

```
[ansible@ansible_demo awx-operator]$ kubectl get svc -l "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=awx-operator"
NAME                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
awx-demo-postgres   ClusterIP   None             <none>        5432/TCP   8m18s
awx-demo-service    ClusterIP   10.104.122.145   <none>        80/TCP     8m5s
[ansible@ansible_demo awx-operator]$ kubectl get pods -l "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=awx-operator"
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
awx-demo-864dcb9dbb-k6xzh   4/4     Running   0          8m11s
awx-demo-postgres-0         1/1     Running   0          8m26s
```